# Second Isomorphism Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

There is one little detail in the proof I would very much like to get your opinion of. Look at where I have circled in red:

[image]

There it seems that they have used that $\mu_2((hn)N)=h$. But isn't $\mu_2((hn)N)=hN$, so that it should be $\mu_1^{-1}(hN)$? Since $\gamma[H] \subseteq G/N$? Can someone confirm this? If not, can you please explain why it must be as it is?

Have a good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your claim (and your reasoning for it) is correct: the circled expression should have been $\mu_1^{-1}(hN)$. It's just a typo, I guess.